# How to calculate mean and standard deviations of data in a r dataframe for an experiment with many replicates?

Tags: r

I have an `r` dataframe that looks something like this:

```
              Control_120 none_180   Control_180 Control_120 Control_180
11722728_a_at   2.473087 2.587434 10.018618    3.449602    2.991557
11716551_s_at   5.345218 5.074153  9.190360    6.555576    5.345678
11757865_a_at   7.130119 7.011685 10.037501    7.668957    7.091063
```

This dataframe is a snippet of a much larger frame containing columns which are individual repeats of an experiment. How would I average and calculate standard deviation of these replicates? i.e. in the above example i'd want the two `Control_120`'averaged and the two `Control_180`'s averaged but the `none_180` would stay the same (one replicate).

Comment: There are several ways. Here's one: `library(dplyr); library(reshape2); df %>% rownames_to_column() %>% melt(id.var="rowname") %>% group_by(rowname, variable) %>% summarise(mean=mean(value, na.rm=TRUE), sd = sd(value, na.rm=TRUE))`, where `df` is the name of your data frame.

Comment: Hi eipe10, thanks for responding. Would you mind elaborating a little?The error I get when I use your code (putting my df in place of yours) is `could not find function rownames_to_column)

Comment: Sorry, that function (or one with a similar name) used to be in `dplyr` but was moved to the `tibble` package. So run `library(tibble)`

Comment: Thanks, the code for calculating the mean seems to be working now but I'm getting `NaN`s for the standard deviation

Comment: You'll get `NA` for the standard deviation if there's only one value (try `sd(0.6)`, for example). You can get `NaN` (not a number) if you do, for example, `sd(c(Inf,1))`, but I'm not sure what would cause `NaN` with your data.